# IGPU Multi-Monitor Enabled freezes PC

Tags: multiple-monitors, motherboard, bios, shutdown, reboot

I have [ASRock B250M-HDV](https://www.asrock.com/mb/intel/B250M-HDV/) with Intel Core i3 (HD 630), GTX 1050 (PCI-E) and latest version of BIOS ([2.20](https://www.asrock.com/mb/intel/B250M-HDV/#BIOS)).
My PC does not shutdown/reboot from OS when IGPU Multi-Monitor is enabled (PC freezes, no video signal, only coolers). I want to use all videocards.

What should I do?

Update: Primary card is external. Internal HD 630 works when Multi-Monitor is enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how many seconds do you need to hold the power button to shut the machine down for good? this may not be the solution but it can tell us where the problem is.

- 1sec => bios has shut down => electrical issue
- 5 secs => os crashed, bios responded => OS issue
- 10secs => bios crashed => bios isssue

Comment: Thanks for your answer, 5.8 seconds. I installed Intel VGA drivers (NVIDIA too). Problem repeats